# Probability of majority votes being correct

Tags: binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given a binomial distribution with $n$ expeiments, where probability of success is $p$. $\text{prob}(x=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$

I'm trying to show that for odd values of $n\geq 3$, $p > .5$, we always have:

$$ \text{prob}(x > n/2) > p  $$

where $\text{prob}(x > n/2) = \sum_{k=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor+ 1}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$

What I tried: I tried to expand $(p + q)^n = 1$ where $q=1-p$, and argue the sum second half of the terms is greater than $p$. But other than the trivial case of $p=.5$, seems like my argument is not really useful.

I appreciate any help to prove or disprove this claim.

Comment: The claim is far from true.  Just take $p$ sufficiently near $.5$

Comment: @lulu I cannot see thank, could you expand on the comment a little please. Also possible that I'm not explaining the problem properly.

Comment: If $p$ is very small then the probability histogram of $X$ will be skewed right

Comment: @lulu, I'm trying to proof or disprove that in distribution, probability of success of majority voting, is higher than success of an individual vote.

Comment: @MatthewPilling, that's true, I'm assuming if $p>.5$

Comment: Please edit your post to include an explicit example of what you are asking.  Take $n=2$ and $p=.501$

Comment: @lulu Thanks, this is a good hint, let me make an edit.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to bother with $p=.5+\epsilon$, any $p$ you like will work.

Comment: Will work which way?

Comment: Please edit your post to work the example I suggested.

Comment: @lulu $n$ has to be odd, but empirically I see for odd values of $n$, $prob(x>n/2) > p$

Comment: Ah, Ok.  I missed the requirement that $n$ be odd.  Let me look at that...

Comment: Yes, I agree that the claim seems true in the odd case.  Not seeing a fast proof...as a suggestion, I'd first do it for the normal approximation.   That won't settle the point, but it should offer a clear indication.

Comment: I mainly need to show it for small values of n, unfortunately. Normal approximation doesn't help my application.

Comment: Right, that's the hard case.  I'll think about it during the day.

Comment: This statement is known as *Condorcet's Jury Theorem* and has many proofs in the literature.

Comment: Is there a similar statement for n even?

Comment: @Thomas: For even $n$, a similar statement is true, when, in case of ties, one decides uniformly randomly between success and failure (note that if we require strict majority, the statement is not true, as for $n=2$, the probability of strict majority is $p^2<p$). I believe in that case we can use a similar argument as the one presented in my answer below.

Comment: @AndreasLenz thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will slightly adapt notation for convenience. Denote $X_i \in \{-1,1\}$ i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with $P(X_i=1) = p$ and $P(X_i=-1) = 1-p$, where $0.5<p<1$ and $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Then we are proving $P(S_{2m+1}\geq 1)>p$ for all $m>0$.

To start with, notice that $S_{2m+1}$ only assumes odd integer values and $S_{2m+1}=S_{2m-1}+X_{2m}+X_{2m+1}$.  Therefore, $S_{2m+1}\geq1$ precisely if either $S_{2m-1}>1$, or $S_{2m-1}=-1\land X_{2m}=X_{2m+1}=1$, or $S_{2m-1}=1\land X_{2m}+X_{2m+1}\geq0$. With this insight, we deduce the following recursive expressions
\begin{align}
P(S_{2m+1}\geq 1) &=P(S_{2m-1} >1) + P(S_{2m-1} = -1)p^2 + P(S_{2m-1} = 1)(1-(1-p)^2) \\ &=P(S_{2m-1} \geq 1) + P(S_{2m-1} = -1)p^2 - P(S_{2m-1} = 1)(1-p)^2,
\end{align}
where we used $P(S_{2m-1} >1)+P(S_{2m-1} =1)=P(S_{2m-1} \geq1)$. Inserting $P(S_{2m-1} = 1)(1-p) = P(S_{2m-1} = -1)p$ (which can be verified via evaluating the binomial distribution), we obtain
$$ P(S_{2m+1}\geq 1) = P(S_{2m-1}\geq 1) + P(S_{2m-1} = 1) (2p-1)(1-p) > P(S_{2m-1} \geq 1). $$
Since $P(S_1 \geq 1) = p$, the claim follows.

Comment: How did you get rid of the 3 ? Could you expand if you want?

Comment: @Thomas I used that $P(S_{2m-1}\geq 3) + P(S_{2m-1}=1) = P(S_{2m-1}> 0)$, since $S_{2m-1}$ assumes only odd integer values. I have slightly changed notation to emphasize the fact. Hope this explains!

Comment: Perfect thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Fix $p>\frac{1}{2}$, we have to show $P\left(X>\frac{n}{2}\right)-p>0$, for all odd $n$ values, s.t., $X \sim B(n,p)$.

Proof by induction on $m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, where $n=2m+1$ may go like this (can the induction step be completed from here?):

**Basis**: $m=1$ (i.e., $n=3$), $X \sim B(3,p)$, $P\left(X>\frac{n}{2}\right)-p={3 \choose 2}p^2(1-p)+p^3=3p^2+2p^3-p$. Now, let's observe that $f(p)=3p^2+2p^3$ is increasing in $p$ for $p \geq 0$, Hence, for $p>\frac{1}{2}$, we have, $f(p)>f(1/2)=1 \implies P\left(X>\frac{n}{2}\right)-p = f(p)-p>1-p\geq 0$.

**Hypothesis**: Let $m=r-1$, i.e., $n=2r-1$, $X \sim B(2r-1,p)$ and $P\left(X>\frac{n}{2}\right)-p = \sum\limits_{k=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor+ 1}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}-p = \sum\limits_{k=r}^{2r-1} \binom{2r-1}{k} p^k (1-p)^{2r-1-k}-p>0$

**Induction Step**: For $m=r$, i.e., $n=2r+1$, we have  $X \sim B(2r+1,p)$. Now we
need to show $P\left(X>\frac{n}{2}\right)-p = \sum\limits_{k=r+1}^{2r+1} \binom{2r+1}{k} p^k (1-p)^{2r+1-k}-p>0$.

Let $g(r)= \sum\limits_{k=r}^{2r-1} \binom{2r-1}{k} p^k (1-p)^{2r-1-k}$. To prove the induction step, it suffices to show that $g(r+1)>g(r),\;\forall{r}\geq 1$, when we have $p>\frac{1}{2}$, which we can see below numerically with the following `R` code  (it seems to be independent of $p$ as long as we have $p>\frac{1}{2}$):

```
n <- seq(3,201,2)
plot(n, pbinom(n/2, n, 0.51, lower.tail=FALSE), type='l')
for (p in seq(0.6,1,0.1)) {
  lines(n, pbinom(n/2, n, p, lower.tail=FALSE))
}
```

[image]

Now,
$g(r+1)-g(r)=\sum\limits_{k=r+1}^{2r+1} \binom{2r+1}{k} p^k (1-p)^{2r+1-k}-\sum\limits_{k=r}^{2r-1} \binom{2r-1}{k} p^k (1-p)^{2r-1-k}$, it boils down to the inequality that $g(r+1)-g(r)>0$ (that we have to prove), the meaning of this is intuitive though, probability obtained with majority voting should increase as the number of experiments ($r$) increases.